# Как получить текст сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

```py
#пробовал это сделать через fsm но почему то не работает

#!venv/bin/python
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

# Объект бота
bot = Bot(token="")
# Диспетчер для бота
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message_handler(Command('name'))
async def cmd_tese1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите название")
    await Name.test1.set()


class Name(StatesGroup):
    test1=State()

    @dp.message_handler(state=test1)
    async def state1(self: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        answer = self.text
        await  state.update_data(test1=answer)
        name = await state.get_data('test1')
        await self.answer(answer)
        print(answer)
        await state.finish()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не понял, что вы конкретно хотите?
Я четко вижу как вы получаете текст `answer = self.text` правда зачем-то назвали message - self и вполне возможна ошибка из-за зарезервированного слова

Поменяйте на

```
@dp.message_handler(state=test1)
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
```

Но это половина беды.
Какого черта вы засунули хендлер внутрь класса стейтов? Для чего? Вытащите его!

UPD 1.
Делайте вот так.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class FSMInputName(StatesGroup):
    name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["name"])
async def cmd_tese1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите название")
    await FSMInputName.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.name)
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    
    await message.answer(message.text)
    await state.finish()
    # после этого данные в fsm пропадают, поэтому думайте когда закрывать стейт


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при какой-то команде бот вывел сообщение, в моем случае Введите название, а потом записал в переменную то что введет пользователь я пытался это реализовать с помощью FSM, если вытащить из класса хендлер, то в хендлере не распознается state=test1(NameError: name 'test1' is not defined)

Comment: Обновил, проверяйте